# How can I find a PID's children processes?

Tags: ruby

Under Windows7 and Ruby MRI v1.9.3, given a system PID, I would like to find all the children processes.

I tried to use [sys-proctable](http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/610/1566/sys_proctable.html) but that didn't give the correct results.

Any ideas of how to go about doing this?

Comment: I'd say proctable is out of date (2006) and please provide a code example.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to simply keep track of them as you create them than try to find them after the fact.

How are you creating these child processes that you might not know what they are?

Comment: FYI: Child processes can create their own child processes without informing the main program.